# How to save instance/view of a Fragment?

Tags: java, android

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/8v5Wfmn"><a href="//imgur.com/a/8v5Wfmn"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Can you notice that when I switch to the right fragment it loads an Asynctask to fetch the information? I would like to save the loaded fragment state (I am very new to instances/savedInstances/states in Android) so that it only fetches the information the first time that the fragment is created.

For example, if you check Instagram's application, you can see that if you destroy activity you will have to load Asynctask again, but when you switch between fragments in the BottomNavigationView they are already loaded.

Did I make myself clear? Anything ask.

Comment: [ViewModel comes to save the day](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Comment: I will try to implement. If I can't, let me reach you again. Thank you @TaseerAhmad

Comment: Alright no problem